# Building several Docker'ed services with same base image, how to organize building and deployment?

Tags: .net, docker, devops

I am developing several similar containerized .NET services that each rely on a reasonably buffed-up linux-based environment, which is same for all of them. Some or other Ubuntu + python, conda and some python-related setup being done. This "basis" takes a bit of time to get set up and I'd like to try to avoid multiplying it by the number of different services that are going to use this same architecture. When I'm in development mode (Docker desktop) it seems to be smart enough to cache and reuse all the base layers on its own even when projects are being deployed independently from each its own Dockerfile - rather smart, unless I misunderstand this magic.

However, our deployment pipeline will build and push the images in DevOps and, if I understand this correctly, there is no cache there - the machines on which the pipeline is running can't be guaranteed to be anything in particular (right?) so, ideally, it would be cool to build this base image explicitly, name it something and push it somewhere, to then reuse in all of the Dockerfiles as the starting point. Am I making sense so far?

How do I go about it? Is it possible to organize it this way? Where do I push such a base image - to our own container registry? How does each individual Docker would know where to pull it from when building the service's image?
How do I organize the system and automate its deployment? Currently there is a solution with individual services in their projects with their own Dockerfile. The CI pipeline would ideally be able to reuse the base image or (!) rebuild it if it is absent or outdated. Say, we moved the whole thing to a different container registry and lost the old one - I don't want the deployment to be dependent upon somebody manually building and pushing the base image.

Comment: You can build an image `FROM` any other image, even one that's in a private registry.  Having the CI system separately build the base image and then the derived service images would make sense.  Designing this from scratch is a little beyond the scope of an SO question, though: have you started to set this up already, and what specific problems are you running into?

Answer (score 0):

### Update/Answer

Thank you those who attempted to help! Ultimately I think I have a solution that I'm more or less happy with for the now - but time will tell, of course.

At first I verified the concept "manually" - I extracted the part of the Dockerfile that is responsible for building up my base layers into its own Dockerfile and manually built an image from it and pushed it to our Azure container registry. Then I re-wrote the original Dockerfile to just use that tagged base image as the base (FROM) image when building the final image. That worked very well already, both locally and in a DevOps pipeline (which only required one additional step - to log on to the ACR).

But I also wanted a robust production solution, without any manual steps, of course. (Or without a person who would know how to run them). So, for example, if we move to a new platform or if the base image will need to be upgraded, nobody has to build and push it manually to facilitate the rest of the application.

I created an additional project in my solution, the only purpose of which would be to contain the base image(s) Dockerfile(s). Currently I only have one, when we understand what kind of constellation of different environments we will work with, we could then organize the files into an appropriate structure or add some other sense to it. For now it's just one folder whose name describes the base image and the Dockerfile in it.

The Devops pipeline now contains new steps to make sure that the base image exists before proceeding with the main build. To check that it exists, there is a powershell task that runs `docker pull` - technically speaking it's more than is needed at this stage, but:

1. The image will be cached locally on the pipeline's machine and we'll use it in the main build, so it's anyway only pulled once
2. The `docker manifest inspect` seems to be a bit stuck in "experimental" stage, otherwise it would be okay, too.

This powershell step sets an environment variable which the next step inspects in its condition. I was trying at first to just fail the step and use that as the condition for the next. That sort of worked, but it then failed the whole pipeline - i.e. it'd do all the steps required, but be marked as failed, and I didn't find the way to gracefully overcome that. So it's just

```
docker pull ${registry}/${imageName}:$tag
$imageId = docker inspect --format '{{.Id}}' ${registry}/${imageName}:$tag
$imageExists = $imageId -ne ''
write-host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=imageExists]$imageExists"
if ($imageExists) {              
  write-host "Base image exists"
  exit 0;
} else {
  write-host "Base image does not exist"
  exit 0;
}
```

in the Powershell step. And then in the next which is a Docker@2 buildAndPush task there's a `condition: eq(variables.imageExists, false)`.

Because the Powershell task cannot log into ACR through a service connection, it is also preceeded by a Docker@2 login task.

### Profits

So, because the base image that we use takes a bit of time to build up - it installs quite a bit of Python libraries, etc - by not doing that whenever the base image is already in place (almost always) I'm shaving about 5 minutes from each pipeline run. I'd say it's quite ok and so far I'm liking the solution.

One thing that I would still have to manually control is that the versions of the base image used by target applications are also covered by the pipeline. I might have to come back to that when we know the pattern of application's evolution.